# How do I apply a composable filter to a rendered array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

**background:**

I have a `redux` store with an `Immutable.Map()`s, something like this:

```
//items

itemID_1: {
  prop1: 'a',
  prop2: 'b',
  prop3: 'c', 
},
itemID_2: {
  // etc etc
}
```

The `store` is assigned to `props` via `mapStateToProps` in a component, at which point I filter out any items where `prop2 != 'a'`, and convert the values into a `List`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  items: state.items
   .filter((item) => {return (item.get('prop2') === 'a')}
   .values()
   .toList(),
})
```

All of these items are then rendered into a grid of `<Card>` components:

```
render() {
 return (
   <div>
      {this.props.items.map((item, key) => <Card key={key} content={item} />)}
   </div>
 )
}
```

**question:**

I want to add the ability for the user select their own filters.

My list of properties is pretty long, and will be volatile, so I don't want to write a `filter` function for every one.

How can I add the ability for the user to compose combinations of filters?

I considered maintaining an `array` of filter config objects, e.g.:

```
[
{
  propToFilter: 'prop1',
    params: {
      max: 10,
      min: 5
    }
},
{
  propToFilter: 'prop2',
    params: {
      is: ['B', 'C']
    }
},
]
```

The `.filter()` function would then loop through this array and check each item in the `List()`.

This *sort of* gets at what I want, in that it effectively classifies each prop into categorical or continuous.

But, my data isn't as flat as the example implies, so something as simple as `items.get(filters[0].propToFilter)` wouldn't always work.  This means I'd have to a) build a list of paths to find each prop, or b) somehow search the keys of my store for each one (which i suspect isn't super performant).

Is this solution somehow workable? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Why not use `getIn`?

Comment: Oh I'll def. be using `getIn` where appropriate. But `getIn` of course requires a path to the nested data, so the step I'm trying to avoid is having to define the path for every possible `prop` my user could possibly filter by.

Comment: I think your approach maintaining an array is good. Just account for edge cases as well.

Comment: Did you consider [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)? It memoizes the method so the calculations are not performed every time someone selects a filter.